# Reducing Large Datasets with MongoDB and D3

Tags: mongodb, d3.js

I'm working on a D3 visualization and luckily have made some progress.  However, I've run into an issue... and to be honest, I'm not sure if its a MongoDB issue, or a D3 issue.  You see, I'm trying to make a series of graphs from a set of sensor points (my JSON object contains timestamps, light, temperature, humidity, and motion detection levels or each datapoint).  However, my sensors are uploading data to my MongoDB database every 8 seconds.  So, if I query the MongoDB database for just one days worth of data... I get 10,800 datapoints.  Worse, if I were to ask for one month of data, I'd be swamped with 324,000 datapoints.  My issue is that my d3 visualization slows to a crawl when dealing with more than about 1000 points (I'm visualizing the data on four different graphs each which use a single brush to select a certain domain on the graph.  Is there a way to limit the amount of data I'm trying to visualize?  Is this better done using MongoDB (so basically filter the data I'm querying and only getting every nth data point based on how big of a time value I'm trying to query).  Or is there a better way?  Should I try to filter the data using D3 once I've retrieved the entire dataset?  What is the best way to go about reducing the amount of points I need to deal with?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb is great at filtering.  If you really only need a subset of the data, specify that in a `find` query -- this could limit to a subset of time, or if you're clever only get data for the first minute of every hour or similar.

Or you can literally reduce the amount of data coming out of mongodb using the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/).  This could be used to get partial sums or averages or similar.